# Machine learning for generating graphs

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, graphs

From my very basic understanding, it looks like a lot of the machine learning techniques for graphs depend on information at the level of nodes. My problem is something like this:

Suppose I want to *generate* a graph which is square-free, on $n$ nodes. I am able to generate a lot of smaller graphs which are triangle-free, and maybe a few which are square-free, and want to use this as training data in the hopes that a neural network or something similar is able to learn some inherent "structure" which will allow it to produce an $n$ node square-free graph.

Are there techniques in machine learning which will allow me to do something like this? Could someone point me to specific papers where a similar problem is tackled? My suspicion is that GANs could help with this problem, but I wouldn't know where to start.

Furthermore, the way I see it, determining whether or not a graph is square-free goes *beyond* the level of nodes alone, and we have to consider subgraphs in this context. Does this make techniques with graph neural networks moot for this problem? I could see how you might be able to encode some information at the node-level (such as the degree of each node), but it seems redundant if you have the full graph structure.